# "Geographic coordinate systems warning" when add a file in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have two files to display in ArcGIS.

First, I add file one, whose Geographic Coordinate System is "GCS_North_American_1983". Then the second file is added, whose Geographic Coordinate System is "GCS_WGS_1984".

At this moment, a Geographic coordinate systems warning occured as shown below.

[image: Fig.1 Warning]

I know that it's because these two files have different Geographic Coordinate System. My question is :

1. Does this matter (As it is a "warning", sometimes it doesn't matter)?
2. If it does matter, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of practice, its a good idea to take steps to remove warnings, in this case ensure that the data frame and data added to it have a matching coordinate systems.  Arcmap does  a project-on-the-fly, which temporarily converts coordinate values from the projection definition of the data to the coordinate system applied to the Data Frame. [More reading here](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002828) and [and here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-editing-data-in-a-different-projection-projecting-on-the-fly-.htm)

**As to what you should do:** You should be able to complete certain data analysis without any issues or you can make sure the data frame
and the data have the same coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

You get this warning because the software's "project on the fly" functions can deal with displaying data from multiple different projections of coordinate systems, but it doesn't really know what to do to convert between different datums. Data from different datums will often be misaligned from each other by 5-30 feet depending on the the datums.

If you're not sure how/why this warning matters, then I assume that you're likely not in a position to be working with data that needs super accurate analysis.

For someone in your position, a reasonable way to handle this warning  and make it go away is to just click the "Transformations" button which will take you to a drop down menu of available transformations.  Select the first available on the list and say OK. since there are so many conversion options, it wants you to explicitly tell it which one to use.